# Does $\int_0^{\pi \over 2} \lfloor \tan(x) \rfloor\, dx$ converge?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

My book  follows the following method

Let

$$I=\int_0^{\pi \over 2} \lfloor \tan(x) \rfloor\, dx.$$

Then using King's rule   $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx$$    we have

$$I=\int_0^{\pi \over 2} \lfloor \tan(\pi- x)\rfloor\, dx=\int_0^{\pi \over 2} \lfloor \tan(- x)\rfloor\, dx$$

Adding the above two we get:

$$2I =\int_0^{\pi\over 2} \left[\lfloor(\tan(- x)\rfloor+\lfloor\tan x\rfloor\right]\,dx$$

Now since $ \lfloor x\rfloor +\lfloor -x\rfloor=-1$ when $x$ is not a integer and $0$ otherwise the integral becomes

$$2I=\int_0^{\pi\over 2} -1\, dx$$

which then gives $I = {-\pi \over 2}$

But Wolfram Alpha says that the integral [does not converge](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+from+0+to+pi%2F2+%28floor+tan+x%29).

**My Question:**

Is my book correct? If not where is the error in above calculations?

Comment: For the floor of $y$, $\lfloor y\rfloor$, please write `\lfloor y\rfloor`.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks I did not know there was a code for it I am editing it now

Comment: There's definitely something odd going on here, because whereas the original integral should be positive, the final result is negative.

Comment: @HrishabhNayal out of curiosity, what book are you using?

Comment: I have never heard of "King's rule", and Google isn't being terribly helpful.  Can you please edit your question to include a statement of that result?

Comment: @DMcMor it is one from my friends coaching Now that I look closely there was a printing error

Comment: @Xander Henderson  $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx$$

Comment: @HrishabhNayal Please **edit your post** to include that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your application of King's rule is wrong; it gives$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\lfloor\tan(\color{blue}{\pi/2}-x)\rfloor dx.$$To prove $I$ diverges, note$$I\ge\int_0^{\pi/2}(\tan x-1)dx=[\ln|\sec x|-x]_0^{\pi/2}=\infty.$$

Comment: Oh God! How could I overlook that thanks!

Comment: But just out of curiousity if it was from 0 to pi would the answer be 0 or $-\pi/2$ ? Should I ask a separate question? If I ask now it feels like changing the goalposts and if i ask again it is a repost

Comment: @HrishabhNaya By the same logic, $\int_{\pi/2}^\pi\lfloor\tan x\rfloor dx=-\infty$, so $\int_0^\pi\lfloor\tan x\rfloor dx$ is undefined. It's similar to $\int_{-1}^1\tfrac1xdx$.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your reasoning is that you assume that
$$\exists \int (f+g) \implies \exists \int f \land \exists \int g$$
which is not true.

To prove that it diverges, note that
$$x=\lfloor x \rfloor + \{x\}$$
So
$$\lfloor \tan(x) \rfloor=\tan(x)-\{\tan(x)\}\geqslant\tan(x)-1$$
And
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
diverges.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} [\tan x] dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} [t] \frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$
$$ \frac{t-1}{1+t^2}\le\frac{[t]}{1+t^2} \le \frac{t}{1+t^2}$$ $$ \implies [\frac{1}{2}\ln (1+t^2)-\tan^{-1} t]_{0}^{\infty} \le I \le \frac{1}{2} \ln(1+t^2)|_{0}^{\infty}.$$
As both the left and the right integral diverge so does $I$.